# How to retain prototype with angular.copy()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular.js 1.3.x. In previous versions of Angular (including 1.3.0-beta5), the following code would copy the properties from the prototype directly to the new object:

```
function x() {};
x.prototype.logIt = function() {console.log("it")};
var src = new x(); // x has custom properties on the prototype
var dest = {};
angular.copy(src, dest);
dest.logIt(); // "TypeError" in Angular 1.3.0+
```

However, in Angular.js 1.3.0+, the properties from the prototype are totally lost, despite the fact that the [migration guide for 1.2 to 1.3](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/guide/migration#miscellaneous-angular-helpers) says:

> This changes angular.copy so that it applies the prototype of the original object to the copied object. Previously, angular.copy would copy properties of the original object's prototype chain directly onto the copied object.

How do I keep the properties from the prototype?

Answer (score 13):

While the comment in the [commit linked to](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/b59b04f98a0b59eead53f6a53391ce1bbcbe9b57) from the migration guide says:

> This changes `angular.copy` so that it applies the prototype of the original
>   object to the copied object.

this is only true when the destination argument to `angular.copy(source, [destination]);` is not provided. When `destination` is provided, only the direct properties of the object [are copied](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/0adc0364265b06c567ccc8e90a7f09cc46f235b2/src/Angular.js#L772-L781).

**The solution** is to provide only the `source` object to the `angular.copy` function, leaving off the `destination` parameter:

```
function x() {};
x.prototype.logIt = function() {console.log("it")};
var src = new x();
var dest = angular.copy(src); // no second parameter
dest.logIt(); // logs "it"
```

**Update**: This appears to still be relevant, as `angular.copy` in v1.6.5 only calls `getPrototypeOf(source)` [if destination is undefined](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.6.5/src/Angular.js#L973-L974).

Comment: For anyone using Object.defineProperty and reading this: The property needs to be defined as enumerable: true for it to appear in the copied object.

Comment: Protip: the easiest way to maintain `Foo`'s prototype when copying is to go `angular.copy(Foo, Foo.prototype);`.

Comment: This does not directly answer the question, only provides reasoning behind the problem.

Comment: Thanks, @trysis. I updated the answer to explicitly give the solution.

Comment: No problem. It was a great answer anyway, just suggested a way to make it better.